# Grouping Wagtail CMS streamfield fields?

Tags: wagtail

First of all, I wish everyone a good day.

I want to group blocks that I created with StreamField.

I am attaching an example video and image below.

[New image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw9Rj.png)

https://youtu.be/VMfxVCGarf4

Thank you for your help, best regards.

**What do I want to do?**

- **All component list**

  - Sub column (Component #1)
  - Sub column (Component #2)
  - Sub column (Component #3)
- **All html blocks**

  - Sub column (HTML block #1)
  - Sub column (Component #2)
  - Sub column (Component #3)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [the `group` option on the block definition](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#block-options) is what you're looking for?

```
body = StreamField([
    ('title', CharBlock(group='text blocks')),
    ('paragraph', RichTextBlock(group='text blocks')),
    ('image', ImageChooserBlock(group='media blocks')),
    ('video', EmbedBlock(group='media blocks')),
])
```

Comment: Yes, I know and use it. What I want to do is to group the different blocks. Thank u.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what else you might mean by "group the blocks", and your image and video don't really give any extra information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Frankly, what I want to do is:

I have a very complex block construction. I want to group these blocks and open them under each other.

Example:

Features block (Master block)
   - Features component 1
   - Features component 2
   - Features component 3


Hero Sections  (Master block)
   - Hero component 1
   - Hero component 2

When I click on the master block button, I want the sub-components to open.

Comment: When I click on the master component block button, I want the following components to open.

I added a new image to the thread. [New image][1]